# Building a List recursively from Facts

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble building a list from Facts in prolog. I have some Facts of "means" where one letter maps to another like a cypher. I would like to write a "decoder" that takes a list of the coded message character and return the list of the mapped to values.

```
 means(a,z). 
 means(z,a).
 means(b,y). 
 means(y,b).
 means(c,x). 
 means(x,c).
 means(d,w). 
 means(w,d).
 means(e,v). 
 means(v,e).
 means(f,u). 
 means(u,f).
 means(g,t). 
 means(t,g).
 means(h,s). 
 means(s,h).
 means(i,r). 
 means(r,i).
 means(j,q). 
 means(q,j).
 means(k,p). 
 means(p,k).
 means(l,o). 
 means(o,l).
 means(m,n). 
 means(n,m).
```

Here are some examples of correct behaviour for decode procedure:

```
 ?- decode([r,o,l,e,v,k,i,l,o,l,t],X).
 X = [i, l, o, v, e, p, r, o, l, o, g] ;
 No
 ?- decode(Y,[i,l,o,v,e,p,r,o,l,o,g]).
 Y = [r, o, l, e, v, k, i, l, o, l, t] ;
 No
```

this is my version of "decode" I'm new to prolog and I'm sure I'm missing something major. I know you cannot modify a list like you can in other languages 
     add(X,L,[X|L]).

```
 decode([],L).

 decode([A|B],L) :-
  means(A,X),
  add(X,L,C),
  decode(B,C).
```

I know in "add" I'm adding to the front of the list and not the end, but I don't know how to do this in prolog. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please format your program properly such that you do not get any warnings. It's really not clear what your program actually is.

Comment: No need for `add/3`: `decode(Xs, Ys) :- maplist(means, Xs, Ys).` or more verbosely: `decode([], []). decode([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- means(X, Y), decode(Xs, Ys).`

Comment: Thank you for the answer false. Awesome name btw.